# What are good approaches to customize a dropdownlist? (need it to look like DDL in provided screenshot)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am looking for a way to make my regular DropDownList control in ASP.NET C# into the style of the dropdownlist as seen in the screenshot below.

[image]

Upon searching it is my understanding that it can be achieved by adding CSS, though I question this.
Another viable option would be to use JQuery, though I'm a novice in this.

My dropdownlists exist already, I simply want to adjust their look to the one in the screenshot.

How do I go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: The only thing I'd say is this looks like Mac styling... Will Windows users expect this to behave like their normal drop-downs? Consistency is key.

Comment: Check `Chosen JQuery Plugin` : http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: Thank you, I will definitly do this! Looks I can use this to accomplish what I want!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among [others](http://www.noupe.com/jquery/50-useful-jquery-plugins-to-enhance-your-forms.html) the ["Chosen" plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) is the one that is close to your question.

Give to all your DropDownList any style name, and then initialize them all using that name, one simple example:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() 
{
    jQuery(".chzn-select").chosen();
});
</script>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAnyId" runat="server" CssClass="chzn-select" />
```

Comment: Thank you! This is brilliant! I knew something like this should be possible, but I had a tough time finding anything I could use. Thanks!!